# Python: How to compare file context to user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Register.txt file in which I enter all user information such as username, email and password.
The content is written into the file as follows:
`> emailadress, username, password;`

That's my code:

```
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rel_path = 'Register.txt'
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)

print('Welcome')
ExistingUser = input('Do you already have an Account y/n?: ')

def add_user(email, username, password):
    file = open(abs_file_path, 'a')
    file.write('> ' + email + ', ' + username + ', ' + password + ';\n')
    file.close()

def check_password(userPassword, userName):
    file = open(abs_file_path, 'r')
    file_contents = file.read()
    password = userPassword
    Flag = 0
    for i in file_contents.split('\n'):
        if password == i:
            Flag = 1
    if Flag == 1:
        print('Welcome back, ', userName)
    else:
        print('Something went wrong.')

if ExistingUser.lower() == 'n':
    while True:
        userEmail = input('email: ')
        userName = input('username: ')
        userPassword = input('password: ')
        userPasswordConfirm = input('Confirm password: ')
        if userPassword == userPasswordConfirm:
            add_user(userEmail, userName, userPassword)

            ExistingUser = 'y'
            break
        print('Passwords does NOT match!')
    print('You have successfully registered!')

if ExistingUser.lower() == 'y':
    while True:
        userName = input('username: ')
        userPassword = input('password: ')
        check_password(userPassword, userName)
```

My Output looks in the Login section **always** like this: `Something went wrong`

Comment: `for i in file_contents.split('\n'):` Here `i` denotes every line. If you line contains `emailadress, username, password;` it will not match the password. Hence your flag will never be set

Comment: Hi Melriax, I am not sure what you are using this for, but you should really not store unhashed passwords. Especially not into a .txt file

Comment: Is there any other way to read through my lines and only compare the password part in the file with the userinput?

Comment: Hey John, yeah i know that its not good to store passwords like this. I just try to play with a few functions and i dont understood why this isnt working. But thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: When you printed stuff at various places in your program did you narrow the *problem* down to a certain section? If you are using an IDE **now** is the time to learn its debugging features, most should have a way to step through the code line by line and let you inspect variables, most will have other features. You should learn them **now**.

Comment: Pretend you are the interpreter. Instead of trying to do it in your head, use pencil and paper and execute each statement in sequence recording the result on the paper - keep track of variables, function arguments, conditional results

Comment: You should read through [7.2. Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), practicing the examples. Then you should probably refactor your file i/o based on what you learned.

Answer (score 0):

If each line in the file looks like this

```
>>> line = '> emailadress, username, password;'
```

You need to separate it into its three parts before doing comparisons. First remove the unwanted characters at the beginning and the end.

```
>>> line = line[2:-1]
>>> line
'emailadress, username, password'
```

Then split the line on the commas.

```
>>> email,uname,password = line.split(', ')
>>> uname, password
('username', 'password')
>>> uname == 'username' and password == 'password'
True
>>>
```